# alias for executing the same command with sudo credentials

Tags: command-line, command, alias, bashrc

I am trying to create some alias for executing the same command but with sudo credentials. In the ultimate case I want to be something like:

```
alias !!='sudo !!'
```

But when I `source /.bashrc` file this particular alias doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

aliases cannot have arguments, use a function:

```
function SU { sudo $*; }
```

Comment: when you say aliases cannot have arguments, are you saying something like `alias l="ls -FC"` is invalid?

Comment: The alias in your example is ``l``. Sure, it use arguments but itself has none. Try to define a alias for a ``find -user self -print`` with a directory as argument.